# jade conditioning to give var a default value

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

Can I do this

```
#{myVar || NULL}
```

in jade?

How to display `NULL` or `something else` if `myVar` is empty? I tried above snippet it display nothing at all.

Answer (score 2):

Variables are declared with a leading hypen

```
-myVar = null
h1= "h1= '" + myVar + "' with myVar: '" + myVar + "'"
// displays: h1= 'null' with myVar: 'null'

-myVar = 'Hello lucky boy'
h1= "h1= '" + myVar + "' with myVar: '" + myVar + "'"
// displays: h1= 'Hello lucky boy' with myVar: 'Hello lucky boy'

-anotherVar = (myVar || null)
h1= "h1= '" + anotherVar + "' with myVar: '-anotherVar = (myVar || null)'"
// h1= 'Hello lucky boy' with myVar: '-anotherVar = (myVar || null)'

-myVar = null
if myVar
  h1= 'myVar has content'
else
  h1= 'something else'
// displays: something else
```

You can try these little tests by saving content in a 'test.jade' file, running `jade test.jade` and then viewing test.html in a browser.

This site has some great examples and an interactive playground: https://naltatis.github.io/jade-syntax-docs/

Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

In Jade you can use conditional statements just like in javascript.

http://jade-lang.com/reference/conditionals/

if it evaluates to falsy:

```
- if (myVar)
    h1=myVar
- else
    h1 Null
```

Answer (score 0):

If `NULL` is a string you need to enclose it in quotes:

```
#{myVar || "NULL"}
```

Similarly you can replace it with any other string

```
#{myVar || "something else"}
```